# About query array of Objects in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

#### Test in `mongoplayground`

https://mongoplayground.net/p/c3UBL9JwX5u

#### expect

```js
{
  _id: "5df1e6f75de2b22f8e6c30e8",
  t: [
    { name: "d1", tt: false },
    { name: "d2", tt: true } 
  ]
}
```

#### This is my query

```js
db.coll.find({
  "t": {
    $ne: {
      "name": {
        $regex: "d1",
        $options: "g"
      },
      "tt": true
    }
  }
})
```

I got the wrong answer, So how to get the desired result ? Thanks !

1. `t.name` includes 'd1' and `t.tt` != true
2. `t.name` not includes 'd1'

#### I want got the result `1 or 2`.

Comment: Do you need to get this `{ _id: "5df1e6f75de2b22f8e6c30e5", t: [ { name: "d11", tt: false }, { name: "d2", tt: false } ] }` ? So every doc has `t` array with an object that has `name : 'd2'` , So your `$ne` on regex will match with `d2`'s & get all 3 of your sample docs !! So for **if t.name not includes 'd1'** what exactly do you want to do ? Meanwhile you can try this :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bl9lDc5X1-G

Comment: @whoami, Thank you,  ```1.t.name includes 'd1' and t.tt != true```,
```2.t.name not includes 'd1'```, I want got the result ```1 or 2.```

Comment: Did you try the query that I've given ? It will perfectly work for condition 1. But if you want an **OR** condition between condition 1. & condition 2. then you'll get all the docs from sample docs that you've provided !! cause every document has an object which has `name : d2` !! Is that what you want ? Or it would be better it you can provide more sample docs & required o/p !!!

Comment: @whoami, Yes，I tried the answer you gave，But it is not what I want，```d11``` includes ```d1```, So if ```d11``` is ```false```，your answer will not be available, I actually want to get ```_id: "5df1e6f75de2b22f8e6c30e8"``` and ```_id: "5df1e6f75de2b22f8e6c30e6"```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://mongoplayground.net/p/CnGnSmRzXCB

```js
db.coll.find({
  $or: [
    {
      "t": {
        $elemMatch: {
          name: {
            "$regex": "^d1$|d1"
          },
          tt: false
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "t": {
        $not: {
          $elemMatch: {
            name: {
              $regex: "d1"
            },

          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```